# How to change the alignment of the title of the SliverAppBar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliverappbar

How to change the alignment of the title in the `SliverAppBar` when the app bar is expanded? I want to make the title's alignment to the left of the bottom when the app bar is expanded and change it to center when the app bar is collapsed. I tried `LayoutBuilder`, but I don't know how to check if the app bar is expanded or not.

Comment: in more complex cases use `SliverPersitentHeader`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this as pskink menthioned

```dart
class AppSliverPersistentHeaderDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return Container(
      height: maxExtent,
      color: Colors.deepPurple,
      child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => Stack(
          children: [
              Align(
              alignment: Alignment.lerp(const Alignment(-.95, 0),
                  const Alignment(0, 0), shrinkOffset / maxExtent)!,
              child: Text("Title"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => 200;

  @override
  double get minExtent => kToolbarHeight;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(covariant SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) =>
      false;
}
```

Comment: btw instead of computing the `alignment:` by yourself it's easier to use `Alignment.lerp` method

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with lerp. will give a try

Comment: lerp is too cool, Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your answer with the code. But I think It is the opposite  I want the title to be the center when the app bar is collapsed.

Comment: Oh you can just swap two Alignment

Comment: Glad to help, play with alignment value

Comment: "But I think It is the opposite" - that's why `lerp` is better - the only change is to swap 2 alignments :-) btw `lerp` is implemented in flutter by lots of classes